# Why does my function not change the text of the property tavelBanner?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
// My Html
     <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span id = "travelBanner">Travel 
         City</span> 
        </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
         data- 
       target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria- 
        controls="navbarSupportedContent" 
        aria- 
         expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
```

// Why will my text not change on the webpage, but does in the console log?

// I am trying to change the text of tavelBanner.

```
     var travelNow = function(){

       var travelBanner = document.getElementById("travelBanner").
          textContent = "Discount";   }
       travelNow();
// when i console log the function the value is sent to the console.
      console.log(travelBanner);
```

Comment: Actually, as [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwnhz54c/) shows, the function is doing what you say you expect from it.

Comment: would it be the text editor I am using? or maybe chrome? when I try to view the web page on chrome the the text still says Travel City, and not discount.

Comment: Then please edit your question and add your full code including all tags. You can use stackoverflow's snippet insertion function to properly duplicate your code here. In order for others to be able to help you, the error needs to be reproducible.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will be useful to you. Run the code snippet and see if you can do something with it. **;)**

```js
  function discont() {
    const x = document.getElementById("travelBanner");
    if (x.innerHTML === "Travel city") {
        x.innerHTML = "Discount!";
    } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Travel city";
    }
  }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

     <button class="btn-success"
             onclick="discont()"
             id="two">Discount
     </button>
     
     <div>
      <p class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span 
        id="travelBanner">Travel city</span> 
      </p>
     </div>
```

Comment: The answer does not really address the asked question.

Comment: I'm getting a downvote because I took the time to show that a simple function really does change the text. And I did it in a nice fashion so he/ she could potentially understand it better and do so much more with it if they choose to do so. What is the problem? And where is your answer?

Comment: Yes, I down-voted because I don't believe this actually answers the question. The code OP has posted in their question actually works (as shown in the comments). So the question is how to help the OP find what the problem is, not doing recreating the whole thing from scratch.